# Is there a way to flag stability of an API with Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

API stability index is important in API documentation, currently I am using Swashbuckle to document my API which is built with ASP.NET Web API, I want to ask is there a way to flag an API with API stability index such as "Stable", "Frozen" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI/Swagger does not have a field to indicate the API stability but you can use [vendor extension](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#vendorExtensions) to document it (e.g. x-api-stability-index).

Ref: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/953f9803bdf4a5051dd4ad90f8a6bc0ad8b6af3b/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/SwaggerExtensions/ApplySchemaVendorExtensions.cs#L10

Comment: I might add that the version number you choose is not limited to SEMVER or other.  Many people will suffix the version with a `-alpha`, `-beta`, etc to indicate that it's not a release version.